# Show or Hide a div element using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I am new to `jquery` and I am trying to hide certain `div` element and then show them on success of my `Ajax` call.
When the page loads, browser hides the `div` element, on `Ajax` success the element is shown, but again browser is hiding the `div` elements.

Code

```js
<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {

  $('#sidebar-container').hide(1000);
  $('#overall-status').hide(1000);


  $('#submit-date').click(function() {
   var processDate = $('#processDate').val();
   alert(processDate);
   $.ajax({
    type : "POST",
    url : "launchapptest",
    data : processDate,
    dataType : "json",
    success : function(result) {
     alert("Success");
     $('#sidebar-container').css({
      visibility : "visible"
     });
     $('#overall-status').css({
      visibility : "visible"
     });

    }
   });
  }

  );

 });
</script>
```

Please help me understand what is happening and how to avoid this.

Comment: $('#sidebar-container').show() ll solve your problem

Comment: please, read this 2 articles http://api.jquery.com/show/ and http://api.jquery.com/hide/

Comment: how is the ajax-call triggered ? if it's an form submit, the page could be reloaded, so the succes-function won't trigger. It could be helpfull if you post some of your html-code too

Comment: yes Ajax is triggered on Ajax submit button click... should I create a button instead of submit?

Comment: is the site reloading after the submit?

Comment: yes... i changed the button to simple button, instead of submit, and it worked for me... Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to stop the current animation queue for each element first (as non-animated CSS changes will not add to that queue):

Also, as mentioned elsewhere `show()` is a better option to css `visibility` as hide sets `display: none` and not `visibility`.

```
  success : function(result) {
                alert("Success");
                $('#sidebar-container').stop().show();
                $('#overall-status').stop().show();
            }
```

Additionally you are possibily not stopping the form from submitting, so the page would reload and rehide the divs. Try stopping the default behavior of that button.

```
$('#submit-date').click(function(e) {
     e.preventdefault()
```

Comment: visibility declared through css will not affect the display:none from .hide(). in order to that .show() will set display to block (which can be set with .css() too)

Comment: @Tushar: Try again with new info above. Your page may be resubmitting.

Answer (score 4):

Use jquery `Show` event.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        $('#sidebar-container').hide(1000);
        $('#overall-status').hide(1000);


        $('#submit-date').click(function() {
            var processDate = $('#processDate').val();
            alert(processDate);
            $.ajax({
                type : "POST",
                url : "launchapptest",
                data : processDate,
                dataType : "json",
                success : function(result) {
                    alert("Success");
                    $('#sidebar-container').show();
                    $('#overall-status').show();

                }
            });
        }

        );

    });
```

Comment: tried that, still .hide(1000) function is getting called which is hiding the div element

Answer (score 3):

The issue is resolved, I created a form submit button to initiate the Ajax call.
changed it to normal input button.
The page was reloading because of this.

I changed the submit button to input button, to resolve this issue.

Thanks a lot for all the help.

Comment: Argh... bad timing. Had just added that to my answer as likely problem :)

Answer (score 2):

`.hide()` sets styling to `display:none`.  You need to call `.show()`, instead of `.css({visibility:'visible'});`

Comment: tried that, still .hide(1000) function is getting called which is hiding the div element... I have declared the script in <head> tag, is this the reason hide function is getting called again?